# Order of WMS layers is reversed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wms

I have WMS MapService that publicized with ArcGISServer 10.4:

[image: ArcGISServer]

When I connect the WMS in QGIS the order of layers seems to be reverse:

[image: QGIS]

Does anyone has encountered already similar problem?

---

I selected only the group not separate layers. 
[image: Selection]

The diffrence between the order of the layers I see already when I display REST Url from ArcGIS Server of the same Map Service:
[image: RestURL]

---

The GetCapabilites from WMS Service shown wrong reverse order of the layers:[image]

Comment: when "edit" the WFS in the window you can choose to "Ignore axis orientation" or to "invert axis orientation". DId you try any of those options and if so to what result?

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I tried the both options but without results. The WMS is not displayed in large scale.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are requesting many WMS layers together so that the server is receiving one GetMap request than contains a list in LAYERS parameter. In this case all WMS servers should render the layers in the same order than they appear in the GetMap request. From the WMS 1.3.0 standard:

> **7.3.3.3 LAYERS**
>
> The mandatory LAYERS parameter lists the map layer(s) to be returned by this GetMap request. The value of the LAYERS
> parameter is a comma-separated list of one or more valid layer names.
> Allowed layer names are the character data content of any
>  element in the service metadata.
>
> A WMS shall render the requested layers by drawing the leftmost in the
> list bottommost, the next one over that, and so on.

How did you select and order the layers with QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

I provided an answer on a different question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260037/6211817.

Please see my comments there for additional details.

> There are two ways to resolve this.
>
> 1. Customize external capabilities files for WMS services hosted on ArcGIS Server. That can be accomplished by following these steps to change the capabilities file and the file can be edited and layers ordered however desired. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/using-external-capabilities-files-with-wms-services.htm
> 2. Use the layer order tab in Qgis to arrange the layers to draw as desired. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#loading-wms-wmts-layers